# .Net 5 Azure Function App with use of Startup class

Tags: .net-core, configuration, azure-functions, .net-5

I have created an HTTP trigger-based .Net 5 Azure FunctionApp and trying to configure the database connection strings and dependency injections for my service classes but, I don't know how to call my configure method of Startup.cs file from Program.cs main function. I am new to FunctionApp based hosting.

I have tried with IHostBuilder like the following in the Program.cs file, but it says: "does not contain a definition for ConfigureWebHostDefaults" even used the namespace => using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting;

```
public static void Main(string[] args)
{
    var host = new HostBuilder().ConfigureFunctionsWorkerDefaults()            
            .Build();

    //CreateHostBuilder(args).Build().Run();
    host.Run();
}

public static IHostBuilder CreateHostBuilder(string[] args) =>
Host.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
.ConfigureWebHostDefaults(webBuilder =>
{
   webBuilder.UseStartup<Startup>();
});
```

My Startup.cs file,

```
[assembly: FunctionsStartup(typeof(Startup))]
namespace kpi
{
  public class Startup : FunctionsStartup
  {
    private static IConfiguration _configuration = null;        

    public override void Configure(IFunctionsHostBuilder builder)
    {
        var serviceProvider = builder.Services.BuildServiceProvider();
        _configuration = serviceProvider.GetRequiredService<IConfiguration>();
        var appSettingsSection = _configuration.GetSection("AppSetting");
        builder.Services.Configure<AppSetting>(appSettingsSection);
        var appSettings = appSettingsSection.Get<AppSetting>();
        RuntimeConfig.appsettings = appSettings;

        var ConnectionString = RuntimeConfig.appsettings.AppDBConnection;
        builder.Services.AddDbContext<ShardingDbContext>(options => 
       options.UseSqlServer(ConnectionString), ServiceLifetime.Transient);
    }
  }
}
```

I have used the FunctionStartup assembly, I don't know where I did go wrong, Can anyone help me to configure my connection strings from Startup.cs file?

Answer (score 37, accepted):

There are two flavors of Azure functions, and the configuration of the dependency injection is different between the two. [From the doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/dotnet-isolated-process-guide#why-net-isolated-process):

> Previously Azure Functions has only supported a tightly integrated mode for .NET functions, which run as a class library in the same process as the host. This mode provides deep integration between the host process and the functions. For example, .NET class library functions can share binding APIs and types. However, this integration also requires a tighter coupling between the host process and the .NET function. For example, .NET functions running in-process are required to run on the same version of .NET as the Functions runtime. To enable you to run outside these constraints, you can now choose to run in an isolated process. This process isolation also lets you develop functions that use current .NET releases (such as .NET 5.0), not natively supported by the Functions runtime.

There are [a bunch of differences](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/dotnet-isolated-process-guide#differences-with-net-class-library-functions) between the two modes, so be sure to check them to chose the one that matches your requirements.

#### In-process Azure function

With this configuration, your Azure function is tightly coupled with the host runtime. At the time of writing, that means your Azure function can't run on .NET5.

You'll need the following NuGet packages:

- `Microsoft.Azure.Functions.Extensions`
- `Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Functions` version 1.0.28 or later
- `Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection`

The `FunctionsStartup` attribute is used with a `Startup` class:

```cs
using Microsoft.Azure.Functions.Extensions.DependencyInjection;
using Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection;

[assembly: FunctionsStartup(typeof(MyNamespace.Startup))]
namespace MyNamespace
{
  public class Startup : FunctionsStartup
  {
    public override void ConfigureAppConfiguration(IFunctionsConfigurationBuilder builder)
    {
        var context = builder.GetContext();

        // optional: customize your configuration sources 
        // here, we add appsettings.json files 
        // Note that these files are not automatically copied on build or publish. 
        builder.ConfigurationBuilder
            .AddJsonFile(Path.Combine(context.ApplicationRootPath, "appsettings.json"), optional: true, reloadOnChange: false)
            .AddJsonFile(Path.Combine(context.ApplicationRootPath, $"appsettings.{context.EnvironmentName}.json"), optional: true, reloadOnChange: false);
    }
    
    public override void Configure(IFunctionsHostBuilder builder)
    {
        // get the configuration from the builder
        var configuration = builder.GetContext().Configuration;
    }
}
```

See more information here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-dotnet-dependency-injection

#### Isolated process Azure function

In this mode, your Azure function is completely decoupled from the host runtime (this is the same mode that allows Azure functions to be written in languages other than C#). You're responsible from creating the Host.

You'll need the following NuGet packages:

- `Microsoft.Azure.Functions.Worker`
- `Microsoft.Azure.Functions.Worker.Sdk`
- `Microsoft.Azure.Functions.Worker.Extensions`

There's no `Startup` class here; you're responsible for creating the Host yourself in `Program.cs`:

```cs
using Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting;

public static async Task Main(string[] args)
{  
  var builder = Host
    .CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
    .ConfigureFunctionsWorkerDefaults()
    .ConfigureAppConfiguration((hostingContext, configBuilder) =>
    {
        // optional: customize your configuration sources 
        // here, we add appsettings.json files 
        // Note that these files are not automatically copied on build or publish. 
        var env = hostingContext.HostingEnvironment;
        configBuilder
          .AddJsonFile($"appsettings.json", optional: true, reloadOnChange: true)
          .AddJsonFile($"appsettings.{env.EnvironmentName}.json", optional: true, reloadOnChange: true)
          ;
    })
    .ConfigureServices((appBuilder, services) =>
    {
        var configuration = appBuilder.Configuration;
    });

    await builder.Build().RunAsync();
}
```

See more information here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/dotnet-isolated-process-guide

##### Copy the `appsettings.json` file to the output directory

By default, Azure functions are not aware of `appsettings.json` files. You need to them to the app configuration via `ConfigureAppConfiguration`, but you also need to copy them to the output directory, otherwise the function app won't be able to find them.

To do that, add the following lines to your `.csproj`:

```xml
<ItemGroup>
  <None Include="appsettings.json">
    <CopyToOutputDirectory>PreserveNewest</CopyToOutputDirectory>
  </None>
  
  <None Include="appsettings.*.json"> 
    <CopyToOutputDirectory>PreserveNewest</CopyToOutputDirectory>
    <DependentUpon>appsettings.json</DependentUpon>
  </None>
</ItemGroup>
```

Comment: Configuration object is not loading/containing the json config values. when I access any data or key & value it shows null always

Comment: By default, Azure functions are not aware of `appsettings.json` files: instead, they use a file called `host.json`. You need to configure your configuration sources to add your `appsettings` files. I've updated the code sample.

Comment: appsettings.json file added but Data count shows as zero, i.e there is no key&value pairs but I have few key & values in my appsettings.json file. What would be the problem ?

Comment: Your json files might not be copied to the output directory. Try adding the following to your csproj: `<ItemGroup>
    <None Include="appsettings.json">
      <CopyToOutputDirectory>PreserveNewest</CopyToOutputDirectory>
    </None>

    <None Include="appsettings.*.json">
      <CopyToOutputDirectory>PreserveNewest</CopyToOutputDirectory>
      <DependentUpon>appsettings.json</DependentUpon>
    </None>
  </ItemGroup>`

Comment: I am using Function App anyway it worked after adding the ItemGroup, but it will not affect the prod environment right? I mean is there anything to add like this for the prod environment ? or this is enough?

Comment: All files copied to the output directory during the build process should be bundled during the publish phase, so there should be nothing else to do.

Comment: FYI, using NET6 I do not need to manually add the appsettings.json in `ConfigureAppConfiguration`, calling `CreateDefaultBuilder(args)` already takes care of this. For my case, this made the section of `ConfigureAppConfiguration` in the example for isolated-process azure function completely unnecessary.

Comment: Hi @Métoule Can you please help me with the same thing for .Net6? I just want to use IConfiguration in the startup.cs file but it's not picking values from the appsettings.json file. And Environment.GetVariables("connectionstring") works fine but it accepts only connections strings so

Comment: @MdAslam .NET6 works the same way as .NET5. I've updated my answer to add the proper way to customize the configuration for in-process Azure functions (also remember to update your `.csproj` to copy the appsettings files). If that doesn't help, please open a new question.

Comment: This is a high quality answer addressing a complex topic. Thanks!